# What is the correct way to play songs on ExoPlayer with Android 10 (Q) and targetSdkVersion = 29?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-10.0

With the recent changes on Android 10 (Q), trying to play a song from the user's device on an app (that targets sdk version **29** and runs Android **10**) using ExoPlayer, prints the following log on the console and fails (the song is not played):

```
E/libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99420 pid 20294: Permission denied
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Nirvana/[1989] - Bleach/01 - Blew.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:73)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:257)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:939)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Nirvana/[1989] - Bleach/01 - Blew.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:289)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:152)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:65)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:257) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:939) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:394) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:289) 
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:152) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:65) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:257) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:939) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:394) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

One way that I found on the Internet to solve that problem is to add the following attribute on the Manifest's `<application>` tag:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

The problem with that solution is that it seems to be temporary and might get deprecated soon.

---

What is the correct way to deal with those changes under those specifications?

Answer (score 2):

After further trials, I was able to play a song using ExoPlayer using the Media's `Uri`.

```
// id col = `MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID`
val id = cursor.getLong(idColIndex)
val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    id
)
```

...

```
val songSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
    .createMediaSource(uri)
```

It successfully played the song without any exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59037794/2373819

But looking at the Exoplayer Source Code.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/FileDataSource.java

Says

`file = new RandomAccessFile(dataSpec.uri.getPath(), "r");`

And in API 29 and above file paths are not accessible in public files.

You should raise a bug in ExoPlayer to use Java a `fileDescriptor` from a `contentresolver` instead