# Exoplayer set mediaSource using ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String) , instead of Uri.parse(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)

Tags: android, exoplayer

How to pass uri to mediaSource in Android Q since `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` is deprecated

Earlier (Below Api 29 / Android 10/ Q) This is what i was using

`mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource. Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(SongsForQueue.get(i)._path));`
`simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);`
`simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);`

Where SongsForQueue.get(i)._path was the path of the file which we got from `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` since Android Q deprecated MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA what can we use

Android suggests

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59037794

use

ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String).

how can we do that any help would be useful

Answer (score 0):

I solved this:

```
long mediaId = //composition id in media store
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, mediaId);

DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(uri);
ContentDataSource dataSource = new ContentDataSource(context);
dataSource.open(dataSpec);

DataSource.Factory factory = () -> dataSource;
MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(uri);
player.prepare(mediaSource);//your player
```

Exoplayer version: 2.11.3

Comment: the question is about how to use ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor , the uri parse id is a known method

Comment: actually this is very helpful answer(at least for me), I was looking for a solution to play video via content Uri, and this helped me, just need to use ContentDataSource

upvoting